# Changing the size of elements in a UIView, and using [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

In my app I want to display a series of user profile icons. For the iPhone6+ I want to use a slightly larger UIImageView (not larger resolution) to take advantage of the larger display, also spacing between the images would be slightly different. In this case is it okay to use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` and then use a series of if statements to change how the UIView is setup? This doesn't seem like a good approach and I read that it's not good design practice to alter the view in this way. But how does one go about changing the size of the elements? Thanks

Comment: Use Autolayout. Working with different screen sizes is one of its many, many uses.

Comment: autolayout wont change the UIImageView size though and then select a larger image for it.

Comment: Autolayout *will* change the size of a `UIImageView` depending on the constraints you set. This is exactly what Autolayout does; change the size and position of objects based on constraints which change depending on the size of the screen (and adding objects to the scene).

Comment: For larger UIImageView it will require a larger image file. stretching out the UIImageView and using the same image will result in quality loss no?

Comment: Whether you see pixellation depends on how low the quality the image is initially. And I note that in your question you explicitly state - `not larger resolution`. If you use a reasonable image to start with then there will not be problem. Also, if you are using the `imageNamed` method then the appropriate standard, @2x or @3x image will be selected automatically. Basically the solution to your problem is Autolayout as 3 people have now said.

Comment: By -not larger resolution I mean I am interested in how the UIImageView resizes. For example if I begin with a 70*70pt square UIImageView with all the images included: 2x 3x. I know that the phone automatically selects the image based on the resolution. But what about if the square changes size due to the Autolayout? Say it enlarges to 100*100 and I'm using a iPhone6+, does it just use the smaller 3x image and scales up?

Comment: This is my last comment. `imageNamed` (on a `6+` phone) always selects `@3x` (the *highest* resolution) regardless of the size of the `UIImageView`. To be clear, the *size* of the `UIImageView` does NOT affect if the standard, @2x or @3x image is returned. The resolution of the screen determines if the standard, @2x or @3x image is used.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I guess the answer is to just use a larger image to allow some room for the UIImageView enlarging. Makes sense but just seem like some quality would be lost for the smaller screen size as the image has to be scaled down a little.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said Autolayout is the way to go here. I'm a relatively new iOS developer, and was putting of learning how to properly use Autolayout until the new iPhones came out in September. I strongly advise you to spend some time learning about it, it wil save you a lot of time in the long run. I would start with Autolayout in Storyboards first as it is easier to use and understand than in code.

Comment: Isn't Autolayout used for constraints though? the distances between the elements. If I have a larger screen size I want to be using larger images, I don't think Autolayout will be be useful in this case.

Comment: It can be used for the size of the views as well.